# Python creating new object of class contains values of older object

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-2.7, oop

I have got a class with a list-variable and a function to append items to this list. I cannot append items directly, because I have to validate them:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, elements=[]):
        self.elements = elements

    def append(self, element):
        self.elements.append(element)
```

If I instantiate an object of this class, add items and then create another new object, this object contains the items of the first object.

```
foo = Foo()
print foo.elements  # []
foo.append(element=4)
print foo.elements  # [4]
foo.append(element=7)
print foo.elements  # [4, 7]
bar = Foo()
print bar.elements  # [4, 7]
```

Can someone explain my, why this happens?

A possible solution for me could be this, but I don't like it...

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, elements=None):
        if elements is None:
            self.elements = []
        else:
            self.elements = elements

    def append(self, element):
        self.elements.append(element)
```

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments

Answer (score 0):

You've got your answer yourself already. Initializing with a mutable object ist never a good idea. It will be initialized *once* the class gets defined and reused for every instance.